# Performance issues with intel graphics thinkpad x1 gen 8

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, thinkpad, scrolling

Hi I recenly bought a thinkpad X1 gen8 and installed 20.04 lts. I have some issues which I suspect that has to do with my graphic driver when I am using an external monitor through hdmi cable but also when I use the built in monitor.

- I get scrolling stutter both in chrome and firefox
- I also get some frame issues on hd videos
- I cannot get more than 30 Hz refresh rate on 4k analysis but I think this the spec

here is my output for checking my graphics card

```
$ lshw -c video


  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:170 memory:e9000000-e9ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Comment: Does the laptop have both VGA and HDMI ports?

Comment: No, it has only HDMI port.